# PHP File Uploading fail

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a script that would allow the user to upload images onto the server. I've implemented the script,though once I tried to upload an image, the script follows through but no image appears on the server. Any ideas?

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once("connect.php");
ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo __LINE__;

$allowedExtensions = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]));
print_r($_FILES['image']);
echo $extension;

if((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["image"]["type"]=="image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "type/png")) && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] <= 102400) && in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions)) {

        echo __LINE__;
        if($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0) {
                $fileUploadFail = true; 
        }
        else {
               chmod("uploadImages/", 0755);
               move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], "uploadImages/" . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        }

} else {
        $fileUploadFail = true;
        echo __LINE__;
}   
        $fileName = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
        chmod("uploadImages/", 0600);
        echo __LINE__;
        /*if($fileUploadFile) {
              header("Location: uploadArt.php");
        }
        else {
             $title = $_POST['title'];
             $description = $_POST['description'];
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Art`(`File Name`, `Description`, `uploadLocation`, `Index`) VALUES('$title', '$description', 'uploadImages/$fileName', '')");
              header("Location: viewArt.php");
        }*/
  ?>
```

Output I receive:

```
6Array ( [name] => comps_tech.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpgQKnMJ [error] => 0 [size] => 661 ) png2529
```

HTML:

```
<form id = "uploadDesigns"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="Upload" method="post" action="fileUpload.php" >
<label for="title">Enter name of design:</label><input type = "text" id = "title" name = "title" size="50"><br /><br />
<label for="image">Upload image:<br />(max 100KB)</label> <input type = "file" id = "image" size = "51" name = "image"><br /><br />
<label for="description">Description:</label> <textarea id = "description" name = "description" rows = "4" cols = "20"></textarea><br /><br />
<button type="submit">Submit Art</button>
</form>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

```
input type = "file" id = "image" size = "51" name = "image"
```

But are referencing

```
$_FILES["file"]["type"]
```

The "file" in the $_FILES refers to the name of the file input. This is "image", not "file"

---

The complete the answer (after fixing other issues and debugging); the last error is that

```
$_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"
```

needs to be added to the if statement.

Comment: i changed it, still seems to be a problem?

Comment: Next thing to check is permissions. You set uploadedimages to 600 (rw) but you need 700 (rwx) for a directory. For now, set permissions to 777 to get it to work, and then 775 (if that files, check which group you're running as) then 755 (if that fails, check the user you're running as).

Comment: Oh - you also set permissions on "/uploadedImages/" (absolute reference, from root, THAT WILL PROBABLY NOT EXIST), but you upload to "uploadedImages/" which is a relative reference, i.e. from where you are. So chance permissions on the relative directory, not the absolute one.

Comment: hmmm.. i tried all the permissions, seems none of them work. May just be Kodingen doesn't allow me to upload files through PHP?

Comment: What errors do you get? add "ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL);" near the top of your PHP file. Then add "echo __LINE__;" in various places to check the script runs through the flow you expect. Type "print_r($_FILES);" as well to check the file is upladed. You need some basic debugging - we can't be phsycic ;)

Comment: ah, I added in the lines, yet nothing's being printed out?

Comment: actually, I get this: Notice: Use of undefined constant LINE - assumed 'LINE' in /var/www/vhosts/andrewgu12.kodingen.com/httpdocs/tora/manage/fileUpload.php on line 8 LINE

Comment: "echo __LINE__;", not "echo LINE;". Sorry.

Comment: "echo _ _ LINE _ _ ;" (without spaces around the " _ _ LINE _ _ " bit, not "echo LINE;". Sorry, the comment field converts the _ into emphasis. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php for what I'm referring to.

Comment: all right, I tried it seems as though the code never reaches inside the if statement

Comment: Escellent. So now add "print_r($_FILES['image']);" and "echo $extension;" to see why the "if" is failing. If $_FILES['image'] does not exist, then it means the file upload is failing (need ot check why as it's a server thing - so let's hope that's not the case)

Comment: I get this as my output: Array ( [name] => comps_tech.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpGp00lM [error] => 0 [size] => 661 ) png

Comment: I presume by the accepted answer (thanks!) you got it. $_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png" needs to be added to the if statement. That should sort you out.

Comment: I added it in, but somehow it still doesn't upload.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give write permissions for `uploadImages`.

Comment: i'm not too sure, how do I check that?

Comment: how are you testing your code? You must have a testing environment set such as xammp, wamp etc

Answer (score 0):

Ur file directory structure should b like this.

1) test.php
2) uploadImages/ (this  folder needs to be created by u ).